# How to install PANDAseq in cygwin using apt-cyp?

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin

I'm new in these areas. Today I try to install PANDAseq to my computer, the tutorial says:

```
git clone https://github.com/neufeld/pandaseq.git
sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool automake zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev pkg-config
cp pandaseq /usr/local/bin/
```

Since cygwin seems doesn't have apt-get, I use apt-cyg instead:

```
apt-cyg install build-essential libtool automake zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev pkg-config
```

But it returend:

```
Installing build-essential
Unable to locate package build-essential
```

There's a similar topic in Starkoverflow, it says that I should install

```
make, automake, gcc, gcc-c++
```

But cygwin still return

```
Unable to locate package build-essential
```

Comment: Define "it doesn't work"

Comment: cygwin returns: 'Unable to locate package build-essential'. @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: Do you need that package? It's only a package that requires other packages, it doesn't do anything by itself.

Comment: You mean PANDAseq or apt-cyp? I need PANDAseq. Since cygwin doesn't have apt-get, I use apt-cyp instead, they are similar.@SamiKuhmonen

Comment: No, I mean build-essentials. What happens when you just go on without it?

Comment: It returns: Unable to locate package build-essential, is that means cygwin doesn't have this package? I wonder if there's another to install PANDAseq.@SamiKuhmonen

Answer (score 0):

build-essential is a debian virtual package.
The equivalent packages are called differently in cygwin and need to be pulled separately.

Use setup instead of apt-cyg to install make, automake, gcc, gcc-c++ and whatever is pulled in debian by build-essential.

PS: cygwin is a library it does not return anything. apt-cyg is not cygwin.